# authentication failed using ldapsearch

Tags: authentication, ldap

I created a local ldap server with Apache Directory Studio. A user entry is created with the uid "djiao1" and password "123456" (SHA hashed password).

I was able to search the user with the following ldapsearch command:

```
ldapsearch -H ldap://localhost:10389 -x uid=djiao1
# extended LDIF
#
# LDAPv3
# base <> (default) with scope subtree
# filter: uid=djiao1
# requesting: ALL
#

# djiao, Users, example.com
dn: cn=djiao,ou=Users,dc=example,dc=com
sn: jiao
cn: djiao
objectClass: top
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: person
objectClass: organizationalPerson
userPassword:: e3NoYX1mRXFOQ2NvM1lxOWg1WlVnbEQzQ1pKVDRsQnM9
uid: djiao1

# search result
search: 2
result: 0 Success

# numResponses: 2
# numEntries: 1
```

However if I run with -W to prompt password and type in "123456" I get "invalid credentials" error:

```
ldapsearch -H ldap://localhost:10389 -W -x uid=djiao1
Enter LDAP Password: 
ldap_bind: Invalid credentials (49)
additional info: INVALID_CREDENTIALS: Bind failed: Invalid authentication
```

I tried the very long string shown as the userPassword `e3NoYX1mRXFOQ2NvM1lxOWg1WlVnbEQzQ1pKVDRsQnM9` and still got the same error.

The below screenshot the verification is successful with password 123456 for the user. Why doesn't the password work?[image]

Comment: Long string is the hash of your password, it is has no sense to input it as password, because of ldap compare `hash_func(input_password) == hash_in_database` and it is very low probability that `hash_func(hash_in_database)==hash_in_database`, looks like password not `123456` if you know password of admin it is possible to change, if you don't know password of admin, it is impossible to change without reinstall or `root` password if it is unix.

Comment: @user1034749 I uploaded a screenshot for password verification within AD Studio and it shows clearly `123456` is the password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose your problem that you not use login, but use password,
try something like this:

```
ldapsearch -x -LLL -H ldap://localhost:10389/  -b dc=example,dc=com  -D "cn=djiao,ou=Users,dc=example,dc=com" -w 123456 uid=djiao1
```

the key moment here full dn of user which password you use:

`cn=djiao,ou=Users,dc=example,dc=com`

Comment: This works, and I can get away without `-b dc=example,dc=com`. Why is `-D` option necessary when uid is provided?

Comment: @Nasreddin  
You not provide uid actually, ldapsearch perform search, so 'uid=XXX' is interpreted as search filter, not login.

Comment: Can you please take a look at my other [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36729629/ldapsearch-invalid-credentials)?