# ldapsearch: Invalid credentials

Tags: authentication, ldap

I am trying to authenticate against our institutional LDAP server with the command `ldapsearch`. My user info in LDAP is shown in the following image[image: 1]]

I used this command below to search by my DN:

```
ldapsearch -x -H ldap://ldap.mdanderson.edu:389 -D "CN=Djiao,OU=Institution,OU=People" -b DC=mdanderson,DC=edu -w xxxyyyzzz
```

However I got the error:

```
ldap_bind: Invalid credentials (49)
    additional info: 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C0903A9, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v1db1
```

What is wrong with my ldapsearch command?

Comment: Server is windows with active directory? If so try `-D Djiao@ldap.mdanderson.edu` or `-D Djiao@mdanderson.edu`, is it help?

Comment: @user1034749 Still the same error. By the way how do you know it is a Windows server?

Comment: I meet similar situation when client run on linux os, and server was windows, and `-D user@domain.com` was solved problem for me.

Comment: The bind DN is not complete in your command. It should end with DC=mdanderson,DC=edu. So, it is likely that it should be:
`CN=Djiao,OU=Institution,OU=People,DC=mdanderson,DC=edu`

In Active Directory, though, users are typically under the CN=users tree (I don't see your tree hiearchy). So, the bind DN (the DN after the -D argument) may have to be:
`CN=Djiao,OU=Institution,CN=Users,DC=mdanderson,DC=edu`

Comment: @BertoldKolics That works, please make it an answer and I will close it

Comment: Is this a duplicate of https://serverfault.com/questions/771549/ldapsearch-invalid-credentials-49

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The bind DN is not complete in your command. It should end with DC=mdanderson,DC=edu. So, it is likely that it should be: `CN=Djiao,OU=Institution,OU=People,DC=mdanderson,DC=edu`

In Active Directory, though, users are typically under the CN=users tree (I don't see your tree hiearchy). So, the bind DN (the DN after the -D argument) may have to be:
`CN=Djiao,OU=Institution,CN=Users,DC=mdanderson,DC=edu`

Answer (score 14):

I got similar error but it was fixed after using -D user@domain like:

-D Djiao@mdanderson.edu

Answer (score 1):

Since I had this issue with `ldapsearch` to bind to a remote DC, I used the other available syntax for the user `Distinguished Name`

```
ldapsearch -x -D '<USER>@<SUB_DOMAIN>.<TLD>' -w '' -H 'ldap://<DC_IP>' -b 'dc=<SUB_DOMAIN>,dc=<TLD>'
```

I hope this would help anyone.